# How to find a file which contains only one string at the top and rest of the lines are empty using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I wanted to find from a list of files which contain only one specific string at the top and rest of the lines are empty using sed can someone help me with this. The text file which i wanted to find contain the contact link this

```
line1:Some text
line2:blank line
line3:blank line
line4:blank line
.

.
.
.
.
.
so on
```

I have tried this command but it deletes the empty lines. I do not want to delete the empty lines but to find the file which consist of specific string at the top and rest of the lines empty

```
sed -i "/^$/d" "file.txt"

sed -i "/^$/d" "file.txt"
```

Comment: sed is probably not the best tool for this.

Comment: @Shawn can we do it from awk

Comment: Probably, but I was thinking more along the lines of grep or perl. Something like `grep -zqP '^a line\n+$' foo.txt` if using GNU grep, for example.

Comment: @Shawn I want to search files in a windows machine so grep will not work in windows machine

Comment: If you have sed or awk available, you likely either have grep too or can easily install it...

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is powerful and terse, but fairly unintelligent. GNU `awk` picks up the slack:

```
gawk '
  FNR==1 && /Some text/  {a[FILENAME]++; next}              #1
                    /./  {delete a[FILENAME]; nextfile}     #2
                    END  {for(f in a) print f}              #3
' *.txt
```

1. If the first line of a file (File Number Record) matches `/regex/` (which you should adjust to match your actual files), record the filename in an array and skip to the next input line.
2. If a line contains any character, remove filename from array and skip the file. (`nextfile` is not critical here, but will improve performance at scale)
3. After all processing is completed, print all indices in array.

`*.txt` should be adjusted to match all the files you wish to test.

Comment: I think `nextfile` is a GNU extension, so you probably need `gawk` rather than `awk`. Also, your dot at #2 will match spaces, so a line with a space or tab on it will probably cause the file to be excluded - maybe use `[^[:space:]]` instead.

Comment: @MarkSetchell [nextfile is POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) and OP spec'd empty lines

Comment: @vintnes `nextfile` hasn't actually made it into the POSIX spec yet, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html (though it does work in OSX/BSD awk too). I checked with the guy at the Austin Group assigned the `nextfile` issue back in 2012 and the current 2018 version of the standard was just a rollup of 2 sets of corrections from previous versions and so additions like `nextfile` will probably become part of the POSIX standard at it's next major revision in the 2021/2022 timeframe.

Comment: @MarkSetchell specified GNU Awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the research.

Answer (score 0):

If `Perl` is your option, would you please try the following:

```
perl -0777ne 'print "$ARGV\n" if /^\S+(\r?\n)+$/s;' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing simple s/old/new on individual strings, that is all. With GNU awk for `nextfile` and `ENDFILE`:

```
awk '
FNR==1  { if (!/Some text/) nextfile }
/./     { f=1; nextfile }
ENDFILE { if (f) print FILENAME; f=0 }
' *.txt
```

If you want lines of all-blanks to be considered as empty then change `/./` to `NF`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -znE '/^[^\n]*some string[^\n]*\n(\s*\n)+$/F' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

This solution slurps in each file and uses pattern matching to identify file names (`F`) which contain `some string` in the first line of an otherwise empty file.